# Google Sheets API inserting records twice (duplicated records)

Tags: ruby, google-sheets-api

I'm currently working on a Ruby script application using `Google::Apis::Sheets`. I'm encountering an issue that I'm trying to figure out where is being generated from. Basically when data is append into the Google sheet the data is being inserted twice. So for example, if 50 records are pass to be appended into the Google Sheet, 100 records are created.

```
  # data should be an array of arrays
class Sheets
  #some code here 

  def append(data)

    # Initialize the API
    service = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::SheetsService.new
    service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
    service.authorization = authorize

    # Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
    # https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
    spreadsheet_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    range = "Sheet1!A:C"

    request_body = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::ValueRange.new
    request_body.values = data


    service.append_spreadsheet_value(spreadsheet_id, range, request_body, value_input_option: 'USER_ENTERED')
  end
end
```

The above method [append_spreadsheet_value](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google-api-client/0.9.13/Google%2FApis%2FSheetsV4%2FSheetsService:append_spreadsheet_value) appends the values into the spreadsheet. I'm trying to figure out if the error is coming from the `range` or `request_body` when `data` is passed into the `request_body.values`.

The method `append` is being called from another file `reporting.rb` which is hosted on AWS Lambda. The method has the following script.

```
def self.process(event:, context:, db: MySQL.new)
        FileUtils.cp('./token.yaml', '/tmp/token.yaml')
        last_day = db.get_last_day()
        sheets = Sheets.new
        data = []
        last_day.each do |row|
            data.push([row["created_at"].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), row["has_email"], row["type"]])
        end
        sheets.append(data)
        api_gateway_resp(statusCode: 204)
    end
```

Basically in the method `last_day` I'm retrieving some records from a DB via a `MySQL2` client. I then iterate over `last_day` and I add each rwo into `data`. So basically `data` is an array of arrays holding the records in the following format.

```
data = [
[2020-08-06, 1, QUARANTINE],
[2020-08-06, 1, QUARANTINE],
[2020-08-06, 1, POSITIVE],
[2020-08-06, 1, POSITIVE],
[2020-08-06, 1, POSITIVE],
[2020-08-06, 1, QUARANTINE],
[2020-08-06, 0, POSITIVE],
[2020-08-06, 1, QUARANTINE]
]
```

So if `data` has 10 records when  `sheets.append(data)` data is append to the Google sheep 20 records are created.

Comment: To troubleshoot, log `data` after exiting  your for loop (before calling `sheets.append(data)`) and then once again inside the function, at its beginning.

Comment: @ziganotschka the array `data` I added above is whats output after the loop

Comment: What about inside ` def append(data)`?

Comment: it outputs the same `[2020-08-06, 0, POSITIVE]`

Comment: Sounds then like your script is being called twice from AWS Lambda, for whatever reason.

Comment: @ziganotschka that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since my other post got nuked, maybe try replacing

```
request_body = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::ValueRange.new
```

with

```
request_body={
    "range":range,
    "majorDimension":"ROWS",
    "values":values
}
```

Comment: interesting you think it may be due to the `ValueRange`?

Comment: `"Sheet1!A:C"` I have range set to be from a to c. But that can be it

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the configuration of the Lambda function trigger being set to run every 10 hours.